# Multiple object non-array variable in JSON

Tags: json

I see the following example in the book Learn JSON in a Day by Acodemy:

```
{
   “FirstName” : “John”, 
   “LastName” : “Smith”, 
   “PhoneNumbers” :
   {
   “type” : “Home”,
   “number” : “333-333-3333” },
   {
   “type” : “Cell”,
   “number” : “444-444-4444” }
   }
}
```

My concern is about the `PhoneNumbers` variable; can `PhoneNumbers` refer to two objects without `PhoneNumbers` being an array?

Comment: no, that is not valid format.  
You can use tools such as: jsonlint.com to see if you can format your json.

Also be aware that quotes need to unformatted '"' is the correct one, '“' can cause issues

Comment: Thanks @BojanPetkovic - JSONLint says it's not valid, but I thought I would ask because it's published in a book so I thought it should be accurate. Thanks for confirming JSONLint's output!